# Как отследить не пустое поле стандартного реквизита?

Tags: 1с

Какой стандартной процедурой можно отследить, заполнилось ли поле ввода реквизита?
Есть вот такой код. При выполнении кода, не срабатывает вторая процедура.

```
&НаСервере
Процедура ПриСозданииНаСервере(Отказ, СтандартнаяОбработка)
    
    Если НЕ ЗначениеЗаполнено(Объект.Наименование) Тогда 
        Элементы.ТрудоваяДеятельность.Доступность = Ложь;  
    КонецЕсли;
    
КонецПроцедуры   
 
&НаСервере
Процедура НаименованиеПриИзменении()
 
    Если ЗначениеЗаполнено(Объект.Наименование) Тогда 
        Элементы.ТрудоваяДеятельность.Доступность = Истина;
    КонецЕсли;
    
КонецПроцедуры
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обработчик "ПриИзменении()" вешается на элемент формы(обязательно должен быть описан
в свойстве поля в событиях), и срабатывает на стороне клиента. А уже из него можно вызвать метод на сервере.

Пример:

```
&НаСервере
Процедура НаименованиеПриИзмененииНаСервере()
    // Вставить содержимое обработчика.
КонецПроцедуры

&НаКлиенте
Процедура НаименованиеПриИзменении(Элемент)
    НаименованиеПриИзмененииНаСервере();
КонецПроцедуры
```

При этом указанный обработчик вызывается только после взаимодействия с полем ввода.